# How to execute Base64 encoded powershell function?

Tags: powershell

I have function like this (test.ps1):

```
function HLS {
    Write-Host 'Hello, World!'
}
```

I execute this commands in PS window:

```
$expression = Get-Content -Path .\test.ps1
$commandBytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($expression)
$encodedCommand = [Convert]::ToBase64String($commandBytes)
powershell -EncodedCommand $encodedCommand
```

It does not give me any output, which is good because i would need to execute this function.
After trying to execute this command:

```
PS C:\truncated> HLS
```

It gives me error:

```
HLS : The term 'HLS' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
```

Does anyone know how to execute function that is passed as **-EncodedCommand** parameter?

Comment: Why not simply [dot source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scripts?view=powershell-5.1#script-scope-and-dot-sourcing) your `.\test.ps1` ?? By running `powershell -EncodedCommand $encodedCommand`, the script will use its own environment and the caller script will have no knowledge about that.

Comment: Becasue I need to execute it as base64 without touching the disk

Comment: ..but you **are** touching the disk here: `$expression = Get-Content -Path .\test.ps1`

Comment: IT is just for now, later the base64 will be embedded in command. $expression = Get-Content -Path .\test.ps1 is just temporary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Continuing from our comments.

If what you want is to embed just the base64 packed code block in your script, you should not use `powershell -EncodedCommand $encodedCommand`, because that will simply run in its own environment and your main script will know nothing about the function defined there.

For that you can use `Invoke-Expression`, but do read the [Warning](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-expression?view=powershell-7#description)

```
$expression     = Get-Content -Path .\test.ps1
$commandBytes   = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($expression)
$encodedCommand = [Convert]::ToBase64String($commandBytes)

# output the $encodedCommand so you can use it in the main script later:
$encodedCommand
```

Result:

```
ZgB1AG4AYwB0AGkAbwBuACAASABMAFMAIAB7AA0ACgAgACAAIAAgAFcAcgBpAHQAZQAtAEgAbwBzAHQAIAAnAEgAZQBsAGwAbwAsACAAVwBvAHIAbABkACEAJwANAAoAfQA=
```

Next, in your main script, use the base64 value of $encodedCommand directly:

```
$encodedCommand = 'ZgB1AG4AYwB0AGkAbwBuACAASABMAFMAIAB7AA0ACgAgACAAIAAgAFcAcgBpAHQAZQAtAEgAbwBzAHQAIAAnAEgAZQBsAGwAbwAsACAAVwBvAHIAbABkACEAJwANAAoAfQA='
Invoke-Expression ([System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetString([convert]::FromBase64String($encodedCommand)))
# now the function is known and can be used
HLS
```

Result:

```
Hello, World!
```